# how would i have both two ajax request and when both have returned data successfully then perform this function()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to call on two templates with one function that when the two ajax calls to the data are successful and injected into the templates with mustache then and only then call this function. i believe i can do this with a with and then statement but i am a little lost on its use. please any help would be great, thanks.

my JavaScript(original question):

```
    function ajax(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "js/projects.js",
            dataType:'json',
            data: dataId,
            success:function(response){
            var data = response.employees[dataId];
            var template = $('#projectbig_tmp').html();
            var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
            $('.projects').html(html);
            console.log(data);
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "js/projects.js",
            dataType:'json',
            data: dataId,
            success:function(response){
            var data = response.employees[dataId];
            var template = $('#projectHeader_tmp').html();
            var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
            $('.projects').html(html);
            console.log(data);
            }
        });

        $.when({
            //both ajax request are succesfull with returned data perform this function().
        });
    }
    $("#header").on('click', ajax);

}());
```

The final working solution code:

```
function ajax(){
        alert('crackers');
        var request1 = $.ajax({
            url: "js/projects.js",
            dataType:'json',
        }).then(function(response){
                var data = response.employees[1];
                var template = $('#projectbig_tmp').html();
                var project = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                console.log(typeof(project));
                return project;
        });
        var request2 = $.ajax({
            url: "js/projects.js",
            dataType:'json',
        }).then(function(response){
            var data = response.employees[1];
            var template = $('#projectHeader_tmp').html();
            var projectHeader = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
            console.log(projectHeader);
            return projectHeader;
        });

        $.when(request1, request2).then(function(t,r) {
           $('.projects').html(t).prepend(r);
        });
    }
    $("#header").on('click', ajax);

}());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the `return` values of each `$.ajax` call to a variable:

```
var request1 = $.ajax(...);
var request2 = $.ajax(...);

$.when(request1, request2).then(function() {
    // called when both are complete
});
```

Since it appears you wish to pre-process the responses before adding them to the DOM you should replace the individual `success` handlers with a chained `.then` call, e.g. (for the first call):

```
var request1 = $.ajax(...).then(function(response) {
    var data = response.employees[1];
    var template = $('#projectbig_tmp').html();
    return Mustache.to_html(template, data);
});
```

At this point, it'll be the template-substituted value that gets passed to the final `$.when().then(...)` callback instead of the whole original response.  You must of course declare the parameters, though:

```
$.when(request1, request2).then(function(project, projectHeader) { ... });
```

Comment: I tried what you said and it seems to be valid as well as outputs the correct data to the console but it is is not being added to the page. am i doing something wrong? i updated the code with new code.

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to add the  `project` and `projectHeader` variables from the `success` handlers into the HTML ?

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller see update - it's a trivial change

Comment: Sorry, i have never used .then how exactly would i wright that? i made a couple attempts but i am sure i am wrong.

Comment: var request1 = $.ajax({
            url: "js/projects.js",
            dataType:'json',
        }).then(function(response){
             var data = response.employees[1];
             var template = $('#projectbig_tmp').html();
             var project = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
             console.log(project);
             return project;
        });

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller Isn't that pretty much exactly what I've written in my answer?

Comment: U left out what was in the ajax call itself. so i was assuming that was what you meant

Comment: Right - what's in the AJAX call is everything that was there before _except_ the `success` handler, because that's replaced with the chained `.then`

Comment: It is returning an object not a string. when i console.log request1 in the .when function instead of a string of html. i updated my code above to show what i currently have. Again, thank you for helping me out

Comment: It's best not to edit existing question content - it breaks the link between what you asked and what I've already answered.  You should be examining the variables `t` and `r` inside the final callback, not `request1` - the latter is a "promise" that's just used for synchronisation.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. that makes since, i will be sure to keep the original content going forward.